# "Attempt by security transparent method" when re-opening a default application

Tags: windows, reactjs, react-native

I created a new application with react native windows, and it works well the first (few) times I run it, however, when closing the application I always end up with the following warning:

> Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.CoreDispatcherScheduler..ctor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher)' to access security-critical type 'Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher' failed.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried this on more than one computer and all of them get the same error but I can't find a way to fix this, meaning I cant proceed with my Native project in fear that it will malfunction every day. 
How do I fix this, to stop this from happening again, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a novice in React Native myself, but here are a few suggestions:

1) There's an issue logged in GitHub on this exact problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1954

2) I personally find that I get this with command-line execution (react-native run-windows) but I don't think(?) that I've seen it when running from inside Visual Studio. Try that approach to running instead.

3) As described at GitHub - I've found that deleting windows\Debug folder before running tends to resolve the issue.